# Starting Android studio promble haxm problem

Tags: react-native, android-studio

When I tried to open Android Studio, this pop up appears:

```
Intel HAXM is required to run this AVD. Virtual machine acceleration driver is out-of-date.  A newer HAXM Version is required. Please update
```

After I press OK it shows this error:

```
Preparing "Install Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) v.7.6.5".
Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/extras/intel/haxm-windows_v7_6_5.zip
"Install Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) v.7.6.5" ready.
Installing Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) in C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager
"Install Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) v.7.6.5" complete.
"Install Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) v.7.6.5" finished.
Parsing C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\34.0.0\package.xml
Parsing C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\package.xml
Parsing C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\google\Android_Emulator_Hypervisor_Driver\package.xml
Parsing C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager\package.xml
Parsing C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\patcher\v4\package.xml
Parsing C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\package.xml
Parsing C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-34\package.xml
Parsing C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\sources\android-34\package.xml
Parsing C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\system-images\android-28\google_apis_playstore\x86\package.xml
Android SDK is up to date.
Running Intel® HAXM installer
Intel HAXM installation failed!
For more details, please check the installation log: C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\haxm_install-20230904_1901.log
Intel® HAXM installation failed. To install Intel® HAXM follow the instructions found at: https://github.com/intel/haxm/wiki/Installation-Instructions-on-Windows
Done
```

Comment: You need to enable virtualization from your BIOS menu: ```Intel® HAXM installation failed. To install Intel® HAXM follow the instructions found at: https://github.com/intel/haxm/wiki/Installation-Instructions-on-Windows ```